# Detect when input value changed in directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-directives

I'm trying to detect when the **value** of an input changed in a directive. I have the following directive:

```js
    import { ElementRef, Directive, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
        selector: '[number]',
        host: {"(input)": 'onInputChange($event)'}
    })

    export class Number {

        constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){

        }
        onInputChange(event){
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
```

The problem in this directive is that it detects only when there is an input and not when the value changes programatically. I use reacive form and sometimes I set the value with the `patchValue()` function. How can I do so the change function gets triggered?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to make an input property of `input` and then use the `ngOnChanges` hook to tell when the input property changes.

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[number]'
})
export class NumberDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input() public number: any;
    @Input() public input: any;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
      if(changes.input){
        console.log('input changed');
      }
    }
}
```

## [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygd9CDWg2OxG6n88zRqD)

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufm4wv)

Comment: ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges)

Comment: This requires an input directive, it should use host listener without any dependencies

Answer (score 16):

There is a better way to detect when an `Input` property changes, it's considered a best practice and it's also used in the [`*ngIf` implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1a44a0b4a87767236f6eea07deca5e4d8789572f/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L113).

You just need to postpone the keyword `set` after `Input()`, in this way you combine the `@Input()` decorator with a `setter`, and it gets called all the times the value changes.

```js
_rows: number;
@Input() set rows(value: number) {
  if (this.value < 0) {
    console.warn('The number of rows must be positive, but got ' + this.value);
    console.warn('Setting default: 2');
    this._rows = 2;
    return;
  }
 
  this._rows = value;
}
```

If you want to compare the new value with the previous value, you must store the variable in a class property, and retrieve it the second time the method got called:

```js
private previousValue: any = T;

@Input() set myInputName(value: T) {
  console.log(`Previous value was: ${this.previousValue}`);
  console.log(`New value is: ${value}`);
  this.previousValue = value;  
}
```

Comment: You are not answering to the question asked

Comment: @MattewEon Wtf? This solves perfectly the problems, since it detects when the input is changed programmatically

Comment: The goal isn't to add a new `@Input` property to the component, he want to detect the change on the ngModel property

Comment: Good approach using latest Angular 7 @Input style.

Comment: If the name of the @input variable is the same as the directive, then you can get a watch on the ngModel. e.g. @Input() set number(value: T) {...} Usage example would be <input number="{{someModel}}">

Answer (score 9):

As of Angular 9+ I can verify that the snippet below is the correct solution. It's best to avoid `ngOnChanges` whenever possible for several reasons and use the correct host listener event instead. The below example will get the current input value on `keyup`. You can easily customize this code snippet for whatever you need on an input directive.

```js
  @Directive({
      selector: '[appMyDirective]',
  })
  export class MyDirective {
    // Add whatever event you want to track here
    @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) public onKeyup(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
      const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works well, just remember that HostListener will trigger a change detection, whether or not you're actually handling the event / changing anything. This might impact performance and still applies even if all components use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

Comment: This only captures on keyup events, not programmatically updating the input value.

Comment: This assumes that the directive input value changes due to a keyboard event. This is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use HostListener. For more information about HostListener, you can go through [this link](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives). Here is the code.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
       selector: '[number]'
 })

export class NumberDirective {

    @Input() public number: any;
    @Input() public input: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('change') ngOnChanges() {
        console.log('test');
    }

}
```

Comment: 'change' not work, 'mouseenter', 'mouseleave' from angular sample work. Please, test your answers.

Comment: 'change' works for select menus, at least (as does 'ngModelChange', and you can get the new value by injecting the `$event` var: `@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event']) public doStuff(value) { ... }`)

Answer (score 0):

To listen to value changes of an input in Angular, use the HostListener decorator in a directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appYourDirective]'
})
export class YourDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('input') logChange() {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```